# Merging different rows in only one

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table like:

```
GymMachine   UsedHours  Building Section
   M1          5            A 
   M2          6            B
   N1          3            A
```

After some time someone noticed that M1 and N1 referred to the same machine (and this is happening with other machines) and now I need to find those rows that refer to the same machine and "merge" those rows in just one. Using mysql, for those rows that represent the same machine I need to add their respective UsedHours and keep just one of the rows. Any ideas, please?

Thanks

Comment: Is `GymMachine` unique? If not, could you show how you'd like multiple M1 and N1 rows merged?

Comment: Yes, GymMachine is unique...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say we want to merge M1 into N1 and keep M1, and assuming GymMachine is unique...

```
UPDATE machines
SET UsedHours = UsedHours + (SELECT UsedHours FROM machines WHERE GymMachine = 'N1')
WHERE GymMachine = 'M1';
```

There might be a more elegant way to do it, but a subquery works.

Then delete N1.

```
DELETE FROM machines WHERE GymMachine = 'N1';
```